# validate date and check if it fulfills certain criteria

Tags: jquery

I am trying to validate the date using the jquery Validator Plugin, but i am unable to get it

What i am trying is: Let user choose the date from the datepicker in the input field and then verify that it is between 18 to 65 years and if it yes, continue to submit..

I am able to get the regex for the range limit but it is from 16 to 65. but how can i achieve above results, somewhat is troubling me..

Here is the code:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
            <label>Age</label>
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm date datepicker" data-date="" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                <input type="text" value="" readonly="readonly" class="form-control" name="age" id="age"/>                
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

The JS Code

```
$("#cmxform").validate({
        rules: {
            age: {
                regex: /^(?:1[6-9]|[2-5]\d|6[0-5])$/
            }
        },
        messages: {
            age: {
                regex : "Provide Your age, Must be atleast 18 years old to qualify."
            }
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) { 
            element.attr('title', error.addClass('error').text()); 
            element.attr('placeholder', error.addClass('error').text()); 
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regular expression

regex: `/^(?:1[8-9]|[2-5]\d|6[0-5])$/`